# Azure Container Instance Says its running Okay but the URL doesnt show my app in the browser

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances, azure-container-apps

I'm trying to have a translator service (https://github.com/LibreTranslate/LibreTranslate) running within either azure container apps(ACA) or azure container instance(ACI). i tried within ACA but the image is too large as ACA only allows images up to 4Gb and the image is about 7Gb. so that didnt work out. so i tried in ACI and there it shows its running, no errors or anything that i can find but when i go to the URL provided after the container is running it gives me nothing except a stream timeout after a while.
does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

i tried following the how to provided by azure and microsoft but this didnt help so far

Comment: It could be that it just takes a long time to download and start.

Comment: Also the models get downloaded the first time the container is run

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried to repro the same in my lab environment and got the below results.**

Step 1: Clone the repo.

Step 2: To test creating and running an image in the local machine, run the shell script run.sh . Kindly refer to the READ.md file in the source code repo for more information. [image] Once the script ran successfully, Kindly check for images and containers provisioned. [image]

Step 3: Create a tag for image libretranslate/libretranslate and push it to ACR [image]

Step 4: Create an ACI instance with the below configuration. CPU cores: 2
Memory: 2 GiB
Port: 5000, TCP [image] [image] Once Container Instance is provisioned, wait for at  least 2-5 mins and then verify :5000 [image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

## FOR .NET 8 USERS

Note the breaking change.

> Default ASP.NET Core port changed from 80 to 8080

Make sure your target port for ingress traffic is set to 8080

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port